# Refer to global variable in Python from a class

Tags: python, global-variables

How to refer to global variable in Python from a class? The code below has a bug how to fix it?:

```
globalVar = 0
class Car(object):
    def test(self):
        globalVar += 1
cc = Car()
cc.test()
print(globalVar)#I would like to have: globalVar=1
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply using the `global` keyword should do the trick.

```
globalVar = 0
class Car(object):
    def test(self):
        global globalVar #this is the key
        globalVar += 1
cc = Car()
cc.test()
print(globalVar)
```

Comment: `//` doesn't insert a comment in Python ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You would use the [`global`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-global-statement) keyword to declare the variable as being global:

```
globalVar = 0
class Samochod(object):
    def test(self):
        global globalVar
        globalVar += 1
ss = Samochod()
ss.test()
print(globalVar)
```

Output:

```
1
```